# How to Know if user Click Button in Firefox page or Default Browser Using c# or Vb.net

Tags: c#, web

i have a button in a form1 called button1
i want to make button1.enabled=false if the user click on the button "Skip Add"
in the Page of Firefox or any default Browser
is there any way or idea to do that Using c# or Vb.net

Answer (score 0):

There is no public interface between a browser window and the rest of the Apps. This is due to security, privacy and related things.

If you also own the web page you can try a few options.

1. **Use your server to push state**

When the user clicks the skip button on the web page, send that to the web server, which will push down (probably long polling or may be web sockets) to the Win Forms app.

2. **Local server and a browser extension**

If you control the users' machines as well, you may write a chrome/firefox extension, which will watch the web page load, and if the user clicks the button, it will do the same as above, except the extension will call localhost:xxxx/.. to tell a local server which the win forms app listens on.

Number 2 will reduce the load on your server, and server don't have to care which user is logged in, to make sure you don't disable the wrong user's button. But you need control over the user machine and an extension for each browser you want to support. If you can't do 2, you'll have to do 1 instead.

Comment: Tnks Man its long way and hard